# sequelize.js - adding a column as a composite primary key

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql-error-1068

I have a table - `source_rule_role` with two composite primary key: `ruleId`, `roleId`.

I need to add another column - `rowNum`, that the new primary key will be composite of three columns: `ruleId`, `roleId`, `rowNum`.

I tried in my migration:

```
...
.then(() => { 
migration.addColumn(
    'source_rule_role',
    'rowNum',
    {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: 1
    })
})
...
```

but I get a Multiple primary key defined error.

When I add the `rowNum` column, not as a primary key, it works.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
queryInterface.sequelize.query(
    'ALTER TABLE "source_rule_role" ADD CONSTRAINT "composite_pk" 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ruleId", "roleId",rowNum)');
```